# JQuery-Ajax code doesnt seem to go within the Success block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

No matter what I try, this Ajax request doesnt seem to be going inside the success block. Can anyone tell me whats happening? This is driving me crazy.

```
         $.ajax({
     url: "/Index/AddItem",
     type: "post",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: JSON.stringify({
         Srl: $("#Srl").val(),
         Description: $("#Description").val(),
         Comment: $("#Comment").val()
     }),
     headers: {
         "RequestVerificationToken": "@TokenHeaderValue()"
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         alert("Done");
         $('#tknGen').html(data);
     }
 });
```

Im trying to replace a  with the response data. But even the alert is not getting fired. So, Im guessing its a problem with the success block

Comment: You can see the response in the network. Is your request giving the response?

Comment: Maybe the script isn't successful?

Comment: whether the request was successful? is there any error in the console

Comment: Add an error handler `error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
        alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
    }
`

Comment: There is no error in the console and Yes, I am getting a response; and thats whats bothering me. if this is valid code, shouldnt the alert be firing?

Comment: You seem to expect JSON, but you're using it like HTML? Also, why do you stringify the data, pass an object ?

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: Remove the `dataType` option, and see what comes out, and remove that silly `JSON.stringify`

Comment: The data is sent as JSON, yes. But the response is normal HTML content. But that aside, I'm guessing the alert should fire. Whats happening instead is, the page is working normally, but the alert is not firing and the response data is not replacing in the div

Comment: If the returned data is HTML, it's failing because you added `dataType : 'json'` which tells $.ajax to expect and parse it as JSON, and that fails when it's not valid JSON. Again, remove the dataType and the stringify.

Comment: Try this => dataType : "html"

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, that seems to have worked. The alerts are firing now.

Comment: There you go, the dataType specifies what format you expect the return data to be, when expecting JSON and returning HTML, it fails with a "parse error", so you have to set the dataType correctly or just leave it out and let jQuery figure it out, and it does a very good job of that on it's own without setting a dataType.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $.ajax({
     url: "/Index/AddItem",
     type: "post",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: {
         Srl: $("#Srl").val(),
         Description: $("#Description").val(),
         Comment: $("#Comment").val()
     },
     headers: {
         "RequestVerificationToken": "@TokenHeaderValue()"
     },
     dataType: "json"
   }).done(function (data) {
         alert("Done");
         $('#tknGen').html(data);
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.error(errorThrown);
   });
```

"done" and "fail" callback are the recommended way to handle result since Query 1.8 (at replacement for success and error).
The fail callback will show up more information about the error thrown server-side.